# IN clause in SOQL not working as expected

Tags: salesforce, where-clause, soql

Code snippet1:

```
list<string> abc = new list<string>{'a1V44000008TyEEEA0'};  
list<task> t = [ SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE (whatId in :abc or Whoid in :abc)]
system.debug('-->'+t.size());
```

Above code segment is working as expected.

Code snippet2:

```
list<string> abc = new list<string>{null, 'a1V44000008TyEEEA0'};  
list<task> t = [ SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE (whatId in :abc or Whoid in :abc)]
system.debug('-->'+t.size());
```

Snippet2 is returning a result as if there is no WHERE clause. 
What is the logic behind this or is it any bug?

Answer (score 2):

The query in your second code snippet will return all task records where `whatId` **or** `WhoId` equals `null` or `a1V44000008TyEEEA0`. Probably in most of your task records `whatId` or `WhoId` is NULL or `a1V44000008TyEEEA0`.

You can execute:

`list<task> t = [ SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE (whatId != NULL or Whoid != NULL)]`

to check if there is any task where both `whatId` and `Whoid` is not `null`.